# how to send http request to a local server on my pc - localhost nodejs arduino esp32

Tags: node.js, http, arduino, localhost, httprequest

hello guys i want to send a http request from my arduino program to my local nodejs server.

would you help me how?

i'll use this code but its status code is -1:

`````
void gotoServer() {
  String postData = "id=" + String(payload);
  Serial.println("************");
  Serial.println(postData);
  HTTPClient http;
  http.begin("http://192.168.1.83:3000/");
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  int httpCode = http.POST(postData);
  payload = http.getString();
  Serial.print("Data: ");
  Serial.println(postData);
  Serial.print("httpCode: ");
  Serial.println(httpCode);
  Serial.print("payload : ");
  Serial.println(payload);  

}
```` `


would you examine this and help me?
`````

Comment: is the port open on firewall on the computer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to pass the WiFiClient to the http.begin() in this line:

```
http.begin("http://192.168.1.83:3000/");
```

try this

```
#include <WiFi.h>
WiFiClient client; //<<need this

void gotoServer() {
      ......

      http.begin(client, "http://192.168.1.83:3000/"); //<< "client" to be included here

      ....

}
```

Comment: that is required for ESP8266HttpClient, not for esp32 HTTPClient library